# how can i link a bootstrap js file and css file to Cakephp 3x

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

im trying to link a **bootstrap js** file and **css** file to **Cakephp 3x**

```
<?= $this->Html->css('bootstrap') ?> 
<?= $this->Html->css('bootstrap-theme') ?>
```

i use this code to src/Template/Layout/default.ctp  and the css file is working but when i try to link the js with the same approach

```
<?= $this->Html->script('jquery') ?> 
<?= $this->Html->script('bootstrap') ?>
```

the problem is the Js is not working, thank you for your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include js like this

```
  <?= $this->Html->script('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js') ?>
```

Or if your js file exist in your project then it must be in **webroot/js** folder then you can include file like this

```
 <?= $this->Html->script('custom.js') ?>
```

Comment: dont forget to upvote and accept answer if its helpful for you :) .

Answer (score 0):

place all css files inside webroot/css folder and js file inside webroot/js

and access the files like this in view files

```
<?= $this->Html->css('owl.carousel');?>
<?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery.plugin') ?>
```

if you want to place all assets in some other folder like css, js, pugin etc create a folder assets or anything else that you want and place all the folder inside it use structure like this

webroot/assets/css/
webroot/assets/js/

you can access the files like this in view files

```
<?= $this->Html->css('/assets/css/owl.carousel');?>
<?php echo $this->Html->script('/assets/js/jquery.plugin') ?>
```

remember the slash before assets

Answer (score 0):

You can use:-
    $this->Url->build('/'); // this refer till **webroot** folder. after that your 
    folder path and js or css file name.

Example:-

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->Url->build('/'); ?>js/your_js_file.js"></a>
<a href="<?php echo $this->Url->build('/'); ?>css/your_css_file.css"></a>
```